# QGIS set the same color ramp for all categorized styles

Tags: qgis, style

I have the categorized styling for my layers like you can see below.
What I would like to have is the sale colour of all the styles categorized, whereas their patterns will vary between each other.

Some similar issue has been considered here:

[Apply a different color ramp to subset of categorized symbols in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320858/apply-a-different-color-ramp-to-subset-of-categorized-symbols-in-qgis)

but it doesn't match my problem.
I can obviously copy the color HTML code between all the categories, although I am wondering about the solution, which would allow me to define the color ramp for everything at once.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the layer properties and select all the categories you want to have with the same colour.
After that "right click" and select "change color", now you can choose a colour for all the elements.

[image]

And you got it.

[image]